# MVC 4: Durandal bundling cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, web-deployment, durandal, bundling-and-minification

My site is built on a WebAPI back end...
the issues occurs on deployment, as my Uri wasn't formatted correctly due to our IIS deployment/site structure

**WRONG**

```
http://itil.mysite.com/api/Building
```

**RIGHT**

```
http://itil.mysite.com/TestSite/api/building
```

So I modified my http helper to include a baseUri
like so

```
    define(function () {
        var baseUri = window.AppPath;
        return {
            baseUri: baseUri,
            defaultJSONPCallbackParam: 'callback',
            get: function (url, query) {
                return $.ajax(baseUri + url, { data: query });
            },
     ...
     });
```

And on my Index.cshtml
added the following to get the set the root/baseUri path:

```
var AppPath = '@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))';
console.log('AppPath: '+AppPath);
```

The baseUri path is correct when I log it to the console from the Index.cshtml: EG.

```
AppPath: http://itil.mysite.com/TestSite/
```

But when I do the actual api call (from my deployed instance), it still uses the old Uri..

```
http.get('api/building').done(viewInit);
```

**STILL WRONG**

```
http://itil.mysite.com/api/building
```

My next thought was that the files must be cached somehow, so I tried the following:

- Restarted IIS numerous times,
- Deleted and redeployed files
- Disabled Caching in chrome,
- Disabled .js caching in IIS (usermode & kernel
  mode),
- Restarted my PC
- Modified the ScriptBundle to try and force it
  to (for the lack of a better word) go out of sync, then added my
  code back

The code works when i use my Visual Studio dev server, but I'm getting the
same issue on my local IIS & Alpha test site... with no luck.

How the hell do i clear the cache on a deployed site :/ This is getting to the point where things seems to be a bit ridiculous. Either I'm losing it, or the "big guy" hates me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh.. Second time I've been caught out by this. I thought my issue was MVC related, its was Durandal deployment related :P

***Note to everyone reading this.***

Once you deploy a Durandal project & **if you modify ANY of the existing javascript files or main.js**. Remember to run **optimizer.exe**.

```
...\App\durandal\amd\optimizer.exe
```